# Rails 4 - Render Previous Template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, templates, ruby-on-rails-4

I am creating a newsletter signup form that is displayed on pretty much every page in my application.

In order to display error messages, I need to render back a template if the form is not valid. Is there any way to render back the template that the user was previously on? Usually I would simply `render 'new'` but in this case, the user needs to be shown to page they were just on.

Kind of like how `redirect_to` can be to `request.referrer` and it will go back to the previous page.. is there a similar way for rendering back a template?

Comment: Did you consider using ajax to post the form and stay on that page?

Comment: Actually I didn't even think about that. Is that as simple as adding `remote: true` to the form? @spickermann

Answer (score 0):

According to the Rails [docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-an-action-s-template-from-another-controller), you can render a template in the following way:

```rb
render template: "products/show"
```

You can try to guess which was the last rendered template or view by parsing the HTTP referer from the request:

```rb
render template: request.referer.split('/').last
```

Note this workaround is quite fragile and may not work in all cases.